# Disallowing certain type of queries in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I want to configure MySQL to allow/disallow certain types of queries based:

- Select * styled queries to specific members
- Queries that will return all rows in a table (e.g select a, b, c from foo where 1=1)
- Using regexes to check against incoming queries and allow/disallow

On looking online, I was able to find that MySQL proxy does something similar but I'd really appreciate expert advice that would point me in a more fruitful direction.

Comment: Woudnt it be better to "interface" the users,use procedures and views?

Comment: Not sure I full understand that @Mihai but I want to disallow users from making a copy of the data (by doing select *) or queries that might include where 1=1 type clauses, etc

Comment: Put particular queries or logic in procedures and allow users access only to procedures,a straight jacket for sql.

Comment: @Mihai - Thanks. I will look into procedures in more detail.